# Cannot run project on Android Studio Arctic Fox. NullPointerException error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile, android-studio-arctic-fox

**Suddenly my app didn't run on my android studio. i already invalidate and restart, clean build, rebuild but this error keeps on appearing. Anyone also experience this?**

```
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.awaitWithCheckCanceled(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:346)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.awaitWithCheckCanceled(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:339)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.getAsyncState(StubIndexImpl.java:98)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.getIndex(StubIndexImpl.java:369)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.getContainingIds(StubIndexImpl.java:464)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:298)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:105)
at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:93)
at com.intellij.lang.properties.psi.PropertyKeyIndex.get(PropertyKeyIndex.java:48)
at com.intellij.lang.properties.psi.impl.PropertiesFileImpl.propertiesByKey(PropertiesFileImpl.java:204)
at com.intellij.lang.properties.psi.impl.PropertiesFileImpl.findPropertyByKey(PropertiesFileImpl.java:84)
at com.android.build.attribution.data.StudioProvidedInfo$Companion$fromProject$1.invoke(StudioProvidedInfo.kt:38)
at com.android.build.attribution.data.StudioProvidedInfo$Companion$fromProject$1.invoke(StudioProvidedInfo.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt.runReadAction$lambda-0(ApplicationUtils.kt:17)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt.runReadAction(ApplicationUtils.kt:17)
at com.android.build.attribution.data.StudioProvidedInfo$Companion.fromProject(StudioProvidedInfo.kt:37)
at com.android.build.attribution.BuildAttributionManagerImpl$onBuildSuccess$1$1.invoke(BuildAttributionManagerImpl.kt:63)
at com.android.build.attribution.BuildAttributionManagerImpl$onBuildSuccess$1$1.invoke(BuildAttributionManagerImpl.kt:59)
at com.android.build.attribution.analytics.BuildAttributionAnalyticsManager.logBuildAttributionPerformanceStats(BuildAttributionAnalyticsManager.kt:66)
at com.android.build.attribution.BuildAttributionManagerImpl.onBuildSuccess(BuildAttributionManagerImpl.kt:59)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$invokeGradleTasks$2(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:332)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:126)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:178)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:112)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:420)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.run(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:962)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:472)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Yesterday im able to build it but when i open it today this error appears.